# Create JSON structure from JSON results

Tags: javascript

Given this JavaScript object:

```
[
{
    "label": "NewNetworkServiceProvider",
    "value": "NewNetworkServiceProvidered46c4ee-7ec1-45d6-9d13-94e301d2f890"
},
{
    "label": "PurchaseOrderNumber",
    "value": "PurchaseOrderNumber4be9f460-0c98-4038-910d-027565f83e1c"
},
{
    "label": "RawRecordType",
    "value": "RawRecordType2a774afb-0fd4-4fd4-a3c6-88041de5b1ad"
}
]
```

I would like to modify it to something like this.

```
{
    "Header": {
        "NewNetworkServiceProvider": "NewNetworkServiceProvidera9ae97fe-e59a-4678-91ea-5a03c7d0f5cc",
        "PurchaseOrderNumber": "PurchaseOrderNumberdf932a47-1476-4a78-a9d0-de538ed8306b",
        "RawRecordType": "RawRecordType12e9d37c-f8dd-4251-bc55-7c83732b5629"
    }
}
```

So far my code looks like this but I'm unable to use the dynamic label in the final result.  Basically, I'd like to replace the 'label' and 'value' dynamically in the new output.

```
var lscRespDetail = {};
lscRespDetail.data = {};
lscRespDetail.data.results = [];


for (var i = 0; i <= lscheader.data.results.length; i++) {
    if (lscheader.data.results[i] != undefined) {
        var sLabel = lscheader.data.results[i].label;
        var sValue = lscheader.data.results[i].value;

        var obj = {
            Header: {
                sLabel: lscheader.data.results[i].label, sValue: lscheader.data.results[i].value
            }
        };

        obj.sLabel = sLabel;
        obj.sValue = sValue;


        lscResp.data.results.push(obj);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple iteration over the array

```
var obj = {
    header: {}
};
lscheader.data.results.forEach(function (item) {
    obj.header[item.label] = item.value;
});
lscResp.data.results.push(obj);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8zpndzLj/)

- [Array.forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

---

To make your code

```
//need to use the same object in the iteration, should not recreate it in the loop
var obj = {
    header: {}
};
//array index is from 0..length-1
for (var i = 0; i < lscheader.data.results.length; i++) {
    if (lscheader.data.results[i] != undefined) {
        var sLabel = lscheader.data.results[i].label;
        var sValue = lscheader.data.results[i].value;

        //use bracket notation
        obj[sLabel] = sLabel;
    }
}
lscResp.data.results.push(obj);
console.log(obj)
```

Since you need to have the object key from the value of a variable, you need to use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

Comment: `lscheader.data.results` contains the data. You could update your answer with that

Answer (score 1):

A "one-liner" would be

```
{ Header: 
    input.reduce(function(result, elt) {
        result[elt.label] = elt.value;
        return result;
    }, {})
}
```

`reduce` is a common metaphor for constructing an object from an array. We start off with an empty object (the `{}`), then loop over the elements of the array, adding properties to the object each time through.

If you are in an ES6 environment, the above could be written more compactly using a fat-arrow function:

```
{ Header: 
    input.reduce((result, elt) => 
        Object.defineProperty(result, elt.label, { value: elt.value }),
    }, {})
}
```

#### Merge-based approach

Another approach would be to transform each array element into a little one-property object, and then merge all of those. Assuming I am in an ES6 environment (see below for ES5), that would look like this:

```
function to_object(elt) { return { [elt.label]: elt.value; } }
```

The `[elt.label]` here is an ES6 "computed property name".

Given the input

```
{
    "label": "NewNetworkServiceProvider",
    "value": "NewNetworkServiceProvidered46c4ee-7ec1-45d6-9d13-94e301d2f890"
}
```

it returns

```
{ "NewNetworkServiceProvider": "NewNetworkServiceProvidered46c4ee-..." }
```

Once I have a way to create these mini-objects, I create an array of them from the original array using `map`:

```
input.map(to_object)
```

This gives me an array of objects, looking like:

```
[
    { "NewNetworkServiceProvider": "NewNetworkServiceProvidered46c4ee-..." },
    { "PurchaseOrderNumber": "PurchaseOrderNumberdf932a47-1476-4a78-a9d0-de538ed8306b" }
]
```

Now I need to merge these all together. In ES6, I can do

```
Object.assign({}, ...input.map(to_object))
```

using `Object.assign` and the spread operator.

The final ES6 solution is thus quite compact:

```
Object.assign({}, ...input.map(elt => ({[elt.label]: elt.value})));
```

#### Merging mini-objects if ES5

If you don't have ES6, you could write `to_object` as

```
function to_object(elt) { 
    var obj = {};
    obj[elt.label] = elt.value;
    return obj;
}
```

or

```
function to_object(elt) {
     return Object.defineProperty({}, elt.label, { value: elt.value });
}
```

Assuming I have a merge-like function in my library (let's use `_.extend`; you could also use `$.extend`), and using `apply` to accomplish the effect of the spread operator:

```
_.extend.apply(null, input.map(to_object))
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [mapping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the array onto an object?

```
var obj = {Header: {}};
var header = obj.Header;
lscheader.data.results.map(function (item) {
    header[item.label] = item.value;
});
```

`obj` should now hold the structure you want.

Comment: You can use `forEach` instead of `map` for looping

Comment: @vihan1086 6 are one, half a dozen the other.  I'd choose `map` over `foreach` in this case because OP is technically *mapping* from one data structure to another.

Comment: oh, okay but `map` also expects an element to be returned. Technically this isn't completely valid and can be confusing to some.