# Create JSON structure from JSON result that has many records

Tags: javascript

Friends, further to my question regarding [Creating JSON structure from JSON results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30091727/create-json-structure-from-json-results) how can i create my object that has many headers from the array?

[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/savvyluke/867mb14s/) and my code is below.

```
var array = [
    [{
    "label": "NewNetworkServiceProvider",
        "value": "NewNetworkServiceProvidered46c4ee-7ec1-45d6-9d13-94e301d2f890"
}, {
    "label": "PurchaseOrderNumber",
        "value": "PurchaseOrderNumber4be9f460-0c98-4038-910d-027565f83e1c"
}, {
    "label": "RawRecordType",
        "value": "RawRecordType2a774afb-0fd4-4fd4-a3c6-88041de5b1ad"
}],
[{
    "label": "NewNetworkServiceProvider",
        "value": "NewNetworkServiceProvidered46c4ee-7ec1-45d6-9d13-94e301d2f890"
}, {
    "label": "PurchaseOrderNumber",
        "value": "PurchaseOrderNumber4be9f460-0c98-4038-910d-027565f83e1c"
}, {
    "label": "RawRecordType",
        "value": "RawRecordType2a774afb-0fd4-4fd4-a3c6-88041de5m321"
}]
   ];

var obj = {
    header: {}
};
array.forEach(function (item) {
    item.forEach(function (data) {
        obj.header[data.label] = data.value;
    });
});

console.log(obj)
```

Comment: can you post the expected result ?

Comment: Probably your label names being same must be getting overwritten by the new label..

Comment: It's getting overwritten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a guess I think you want this:

```
array.forEach(function (item) {
    item.forEach(function (data) {
        obj.header[data.label] = obj.header[data.label] || [];
        obj.header[data.label].push(data.value);
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/867mb14s/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your `array` is incorrect. the JS code you provided works perfectly if you have **different label names**, if label names are same then the latest values will replace the old values.

So , try this code. it gives all header names.

```js
var array = [
  [{
    "label": "0_NewNetworkServiceProvider",
    "value": "0_NewNetworkServiceProvidered46c4ee-7ec1-45d6-9d13-94e301d2f890"
  }, {
    "label": "0_PurchaseOrderNumber",
    "value": "0_PurchaseOrderNumber4be9f460-0c98-4038-910d-027565f83e1c"
  }, {
    "label": "0_RawRecordType",
    "value": "0_RawRecordType2a774afb-0fd4-4fd4-a3c6-88041de5b1ad"
  }],
  [{
    "label": "1_NewNetworkServiceProvider",
    "value": "1_NewNetworkServiceProvidered46c4ee-7ec1-45d6-9d13-94e301d2f890"
  }, {
    "label": "1_PurchaseOrderNumber",
    "value": "1_PurchaseOrderNumber4be9f460-0c98-4038-910d-027565f83e1c"
  }, {
    "label": "1_RawRecordType",
    "value": "1_RawRecordType2a774afb-0fd4-4fd4-a3c6-88041de5m321"
  }]
];

var obj = {
  header: {}
};
array.forEach(function(item) {
  item.forEach(function(data) {
    obj.header[data.label] = data.value;
  });
});

console.log(obj)
```

**See the difference in `array` data.**

And @Jaromanda X is also correct, but he is fetching records as array inside each header.